# Create two dependent Select attributes

Tags: wordpress, attributes

I have made a site using listinghive. Im almost at the end, but i have some problems. When i go to add new listing then choose category cars, and then i have a lot of attributes. I have BRAND and its dropdown menu with all car brands from a to z. And i have next attribute MODEL. I would like when i choose in BRAND for example AUDI i will in MODEL only see A1 A2 A3 etc etc so is there any solution for that? Or something else… please help

I create attributes for car listing website, but can't depend its

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.